# Can files be deleted in a folder if they don't contain a specific word using Power Automate?

Tags: power-automate

I currently have a folder which has photos dumped into it, I am looking to delete all files that do not contain a specific word (which is present in all file names in which I want to keep).

I am hoping this can be done with power automate as there is 100's of photos and I want to improve its efficiency.

I look forward to learning from somebody!

Image below, it seems the flow ran successfully.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBnuZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Get files (properties only) action and use a filter array afterwards. In the filter array you could check if the Name field does not contain your keyword.

After that you can loop through the results of the filter array and delete the files based on the {Identifier} field.

Below is an example of that approach
*Test it properly, because you are deleting files. Otherwise restore from the first or second stage recycle bin ;)*

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, I created the flow as above however its not deleting the files that dont contain a certain word, do you have anymore advice please?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the outputs of your Filter Array action from the flow run history where it did not work?

Comment: Sure, can I attach in this comments section? doesn't seem to have an option to.

Comment: I don't think comments support attachments. Can you add it to your opening post/question?

Comment: got it, image now attached on the original post, thanks!

Comment: Your filter array output is empty. So, none of your files meet the condition. We need to correct/troubleshoot that part of the configuration. 

Can you show a couple of example file names which you expect to be deleted and also show the configuration of your filter array action in a screenshot? Might also be useful to copy past the raw outputs of your get files action as well.